# SULU CMF: Direct upload in media_selection

Tags: sulu

I have a page with a field of type media_selection.
The configuration is like that one.

```
<property name="images" type="media_selection">
    <meta>
        <title lang="de">Bilder</title>
        <title lang="en">Images</title>
    </meta>

    <tag name="sulu.search.field" role="image" index="false"/>
    <tag name="sulu.content.sortmode.show"/>
</property>
```

Is it possible to upload a file directly from the page
in the backend? It work's for me if I have the image already uploaded in the media-manager but that's kind of inconvinient for the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's possible, when you choose a selection in the overlay you can just drag&drop images or click the button with the plus sign saying `Click or Drag'n'Drop`:

[image]